# How can I create a new environment and make the first paragraph after it withouth indentation?

Tags: environments, koma-script, indentation

I created my own environment and it in/for a KOMA-class.

It works fine, except that the first paragraph after it has an indentation. It want it to have no indentation at all, which is why I use `false-` for the class.

How can I set that indentation to zero?

## Screenshot

[image]

## MWE

```
\documentclass[
11pt,
a4paper,
]
{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
lmodern,
blindtext
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{
multicol,
blindtext,
}

\newenvironment{teaser}{\vspace{0ex}\par\raggedright\sffamily}{%
\par%
\rule{0.8\columnwidth}{1pt}\par
\vspace{2ex}%
}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\begin{center}\huge
Title stuff
\end{center}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\section{Word}

\begin{teaser}
Stuff.
Word, some text to fill the void.
Here is a longer sentence, quite the long one.
\end{teaser}%
%
How do I have to define the new environment \verb|teaser| so that the first paragraph after it has no indentation?

Words words words words words words words words words words words words words.
Words words words words.
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\rule{0.8\columnwidth}{1pt}\par\noindent`.

Comment: `\rule{0.8\columnwidth}{1pt}\par\csname @afterheading\endcsname` should work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer For everyone's consideration: Ulrike's comment has a working solution! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\@afterheading`, which is what LaTeX does after section titles.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{teaser}
 {%
  \par\raggedright\sffamily
 }
 {%
  \par
  \rule{0.8\columnwidth}{1pt}\par\addvspace{2ex}%
  \@afterheading
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{center}\huge
Title stuff
\end{center}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\section{Word}

\begin{teaser}
Stuff.
Word, some text to fill the void.
Here is a longer sentence, quite the long one.
\end{teaser}

How do I have to define the new environment \verb|teaser| so that the first 
paragraph after it has no indentation?

Words words words words words words words words words words words words words.
Words words words words.
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thought I would try your code without `\makeatletter` & `\makeatother`, but it breaks. Why does Ulrike's code https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/587108/how-can-i-create-a-new-environment-and-make-the-first-paragraph-after-it-without?noredirect=1#comment1475173_587108 work then? :)

Comment: @henry Because she proposes `\csname @afterheading\endcsname` and with this it's immaterial whether the code is between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` or not. Is there something against `\makeatletter`? You're accessing an internal function of LaTeX, so you mark the code for making it clear.

Comment: Oh, there is not! I was just curious and broadening my LaTeX knowledge in order to once again go googling for it in 3 months when I forgot what was what (when I go through my document). ;)